# Add column to pandas without headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How does one append a column of constant values to a pandas dataframe without headers? I want to append the column at the end.

With headers I can do it [this](http://[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039023/add-column-with-constant-value-to-pandas-dataframe]) way:

```
df['new'] = pd.Series([0 for x in range(len(df.index))], index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each not empty [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) has `columns`, `index` and some values.

You can add default column value and create new column filled by scalar:

```
df[len(df.columns)] = 0
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0:[1,2,3],
                   1:[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   0  1
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df[len(df.columns)] = 0
print (df)
   0  1  2
0  1  4  0
1  2  5  0
2  3  6  0
```

Also for creating new column with name the simpliest is:

```
df['new'] = 1
```