# How to add a calculated column that gives aggregation of rows but maintains the shape of the dataframe in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with sales orders and I want to get the count of the orderlines per order in every row:

```
Order   Orderline   
1       0             
1       1             
1       2             
2       0             
3       0             
3       1
```

What I would like to obtain is

```
Order   Orderline   Count   
1       0           3  
1       1           3 
1       2           3
2       0           1  
3       0           2  
3       1           2
```

I tried using `transform('count')` as I noticed it being used in [How to add a new column and fill it up with a specific value depending on another column's series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61352142/how-to-add-a-new-column-and-fill-it-up-with-a-specific-value-depending-on-anothe) but that didn't work out. It flattened down my table instead.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: `df['Count'] = df.groupby("Order")['Orderline'].transform('count')` works for me

Comment: Thank you @anky, that worked out for me. Please make it an answer so I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `groupby` and then `transform`:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(by=['Order'], as_index=False).transform('count')
print(df)

   Order  Orderline  Count
0      1          0      3
1      1          1      3
2      1          2      3
3      2          0      1
4      3          0      2
5      3          1      2
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upvote your answer as I don't have enough reputation yet. Thank you for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df['counts'] = df.apply(lambda x: (df['Order'] == x['Order']).sum(), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It will work I'm sure. I read that apply should be avoided and transform is way more performant. I'm having a dataset with millions of rows so performance is also important to me.