# Write function to add columns to dataframe

Tags: python, function, dataframe

Hi I would like to write a function to add two columns to my dataframe below:

```
ID             NUMBER      OBJECT
1345471886     SIZE-43     GHJ  
1481654311     SIZE-48     IJF   
8620787660     SIZE-67     EFH
```

This is my code:

```
def add_columns(res):
    
    h = res.assign(Column_1='Value_1', Column_2='Value_2')
    return h
print(h)
```

I get NameError: name 'h' is not defined

My expected output would be:

```
ID             NUMBER      OBJECT  Column_1    Column_2
1345471886     SIZE-43     GHJ     Value_1     Value_2
1481654311     SIZE-48     IJF     Value_1     Value_2
8620787660     SIZE-67     EFH     Value_1     Value_2
```

Can you please help? Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by: [Add column with constant value to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039023/add-column-with-constant-value-to-pandas-dataframe)

**Code**

```
from io import StringIO

def add_column(df, name, value):
    '''
        Adds a single column to DataFrame
    '''
    df[name] = pd.Series([value for x in range(len(df.index))], index=df.index)
    
    return df
```

**Usage**

```
s = '''ID             NUMBER      OBJECT
1345471886     SIZE-43     GHJ
1481654311     SIZE-48     IJF
8620787660     SIZE-67     EFH '''

# Create DataFrame
df = df =pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delim_whitespace=True) 

# Use function above to add 2 columns
add_column(df, "Column_1", "Value_1")
add_column(df, "Column_2", "Value_2")

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
          ID   NUMBER OBJECT Column_1 Column_2
0  1345471886  SIZE-43    GHJ  Value_1  Value_2
1  1481654311  SIZE-48    IJF  Value_1  Value_2
2  8620787660  SIZE-67    EFH  Value_1  Value_2
```