# How to save a Dictionary inside a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

**Context**

I have a `Pandas` `DataFrame` and a `Use Case`, where I need to store a `Collection` (`Dictionary`) in of the `Columns`. I do know, that a `DataFrame` is probably not designed for this, however, I am looking for a simple solution without `Relationships` between multiple `DataFrames`, `Series`, etc.

I am currently getting the following Error:

> ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (5)

---

**Code**

```py
procedures = {'A': 'Procedure A', 'B': 'Procedure B', 'C': 'Procedure C'}

# I would like to create a new Column 'Procedures' and assign the Dictionary above to it for every Row.
data['Procedures'] = procedures
```

---

**Question**

- Is this possible with `Pandas` and how can I achieve it?

Comment: See the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54345943/9327572

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat list of dict by multiple by length of DataFrame:

```
data['Procedures'] = [procedures] * len(data)
```

Answer (score -1):

To save a Dictionary inside a Pandas DataFrame use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(input_dict)`.

If you think it's not clear, refer to [this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-dictionary-to-pandas-dataframe/#:%7E:text=We%20can%20convert%20a%20dictionary,from_dict()%20class%2Dmethod.).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, this is not what I am trying to achieve.